# How do I paginate a pre-sorted record collection using will_paginate?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sorting, pagination, will-paginate

How do I paginate a pre-sorted record collection using will_paginate?

Environment: Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.3, Windows 8.1, PostreSQL, Datatable 1.12.2, Will_Paginate 3.0.5

Using Railscast 340 code, I am trying to finalize my datatable implementation.  I have several columns that I need to sort independently because they exist in associations and cannot be accessed directly.  I've only shown one column in one direction for simplicity.

The sort is working in both the standard case and in the "product_location" case.  The correct records are available in the record collection and they are in the correct order in both cases.

In the "product_location" case, when I try to paginate the result, will_paginate seems to retrieve records from the table instead of using my record collection.  I end up with the wrong records in the wrong order.  This action doesn't make sense to me, so I must be missing something.

The standard sort is working in both directions on all columns.

My code is as follows, and after that is the original code from Railscast 340:

```
  def products
    @products ||= fetch_products
  end

  def fetch_products
    case sort_column
      when "product_location"
        products = Product.all
        products.sort_by!{|product| product.readable_loc} # product_location sort
      else
        products = Product.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}") # standard sort
    end

    # products is correctly sorted in both cases at this point

    products = products.page(page).per_page(per_page)

    # At this point, products is correctly sorted in the standard case but not in the "product_location" case
    # In "product_location" case, pagination seems to be accessing the table directly again, not using the record collection?

    if params[:sSearch].present?
      products = products.where("stock_number like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
    end
    products
  end
```

The original code is:

```
  def products
    @products ||= fetch_products
  end

  def fetch_products
    products = Product.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    products = products.page(page).per_page(per_page)
    if params[:sSearch].present?
      products = products.where("name like :search or category like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
    end
    products
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `Product.all` returns instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` and `products.sort_by!` fetches all records from database a sort them with ruby. Than if you call `products = products.page(page).per_page(per_page)` it creates new sql query with new `limit` and `offset` to fetch records on given page.

So if you want to use will_paginate for pagination, you cannot use `.sort_by!` method for data sorting, but you have to order records with `Products.order` which will sort records via SQL in the database.

Comment: Hi! That's an issue discussed in question 24001705.  I'd much rather do it through Products.order.  But, these columns are not native but instead are built through polymorphic associations.  Can you help me answer that question?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to add answer to that question.